# Localized files in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, resources

I'm developing an application that shows some data from localized files with json content. At the moment the content files are translated into 3 languages: 

 - PL, EN and PT
 - number of files per language may vary
 - same name of the file may exist for two languages

The thing I'd like to achieve is to store those files and copy them into isolated storage and then access them according to current culture. I know how to do that manually by putting those files into custom folders and handling all access by my custom code, but thats not the point.

In Android I can use such file strucure:

raw

raw-pl

raw-en

And when I request for files from 'raw' folder, I'll get files from the folder with current selected culture. Does Windows Phone 8 supports something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 8 / the .NET framework has lots of built in features to support localization. It sounds like you'll be particularly interested in [resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231537.aspx) for storing your culture specific strings.

Some useful code examples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx

You can use the resource files to store any type of localized string for any purpose within the app, not just for direct binding to UI XAML controls.

Comment: I'm familiar with usage of resources in .Net apps, but in this case it requires from me to generate extra resx files to store the content of files. In my case it would require more work to implement such mechanism.

Comment: If you don't want to use the built-in localization support you'll probably need to roll your own and use the culture of the phone to switch between your directories. Should be quick and easy to knock up your own custom isolated storage helper that switches source directory based on current culture of the phone.